# Tomcat as a windows service: redistributing tomcat with JRE

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I need to distribute my webapp on Tomcat 7 with JRE and override (if clients have) the JAVA_HOME setup in their own machines. I need to be able to install tomcat as a windows service and start/stop it. I cannot install tomcat as a windows service using service.bat. It needs JDK, JRE would not work. I set JAVA_HOME pointing to JRE and it would not work. Is there a way to install service without using JDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- set JRE_HOME point it to JRE.
- Unset JAVA_HOME
- call service.bat